# How do I assign IP address from text file to hostname in python script

Tags: python, variables, authentication, hostname, ftplib

I am able to retreive and assign username and password from text and pass it to ftplib for "ftp.login"

How can I do the same thing for an IP address in a text file that I want to pass to "ftplib.FTP("0.0.0.0")" instead of the (0.0.0.0) want to replace it with "ftplib.FTP(hostname)?

here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ftplib
import os
import sys
import paramiko
import datetime
import pickle
import ftplib as ftp
import socket




login = {}
with open('hostname1.txt', 'r') as g:
   for line in g:
       hostname = line.strip()
       login[hostname] = hostname


credentials = {}
with open('Usernames.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        username, password = line.strip().split(':')
        credentials[username] = password

try:
        try:
            print "Connecting to 192.168.189.130"
            ftp = ftplib.FTP(hostname)
            ftp.login(username, password)
            ftp.cwd('dir1')
            ftp.retrlines('LIST')
#           ftp.get()

        except ftplib.all_errors as e:
            print(e)
except ftp.login as s:
    print (s)
```

Comment: could you give a simple format of the text files 'hostname1.txt' and 'Usernames.txt' and also if the above code runs could you paste the output

Comment: machine1# cat Usernames.txt
ftpclient1:password

Comment: machine1# cat hostname1.txt
192.168.189.130

Comment: as i said can l read the username and password text files find

Comment: i can not read or pass the IP address to hostname for ftplib.FTP(0.0.0.0), in which would like to replace the IP address with "hostname" ftplib.FTP(hostname)

Comment: Could paste the ouput with "0.0.0.0" or paste traceback

Comment: this is the output when using the IP address in "ftplib.FTP("0.0.0.0") ....  machine1@machine1:~$ ./login.py
Connecting to 0.0.0.0
-rw-rw-r--   1 ftpclient1 ftpclient1        0 Jun 26 20:38 file1_20150629.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 ftpclient1 ftpclient1        0 Jun 26 20:38 file2_20150629.txt
-rw-rw-r--   1 ftpclient1 ftpclient1        0 Jun 26 20:38 file3_20150629.txt
machine1@machine1:~$

Comment: could you paste the answer and how you got through the solution for viewers ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks "Praneeth" for quick response!

Answered my own question.

This works!

simple mistake on my part... did not remove the double quotes "" in the () with the ftplib.FTP(hostname) line.....

Please use it works great!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ftplib
import os
import sys
import paramiko
import datetime
import pickle
import ftplib as ftp
import socket




login = {}
with open('hostname1.txt', 'r') as g:
   for line in g:
       hostname = line.strip()
       login[hostname] = hostname


credentials = {}
with open('Usernames.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        username, password = line.strip().split(':')
        credentials[username] = password

try:
        try:
            print "Connecting to 0.0.0.0"
            ftp = ftplib.FTP(hostname)
            ftp.login(username, password)
            ftp.cwd('dir1')
            ftp.retrlines('LIST')
#           ftp.get()

        except ftplib.all_errors as e:
            print(e)
except ftp.login as s:
    print (s)
```